# Наследование в Django 1.8.2 и Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, у меня стоит задача перевода проекта с django версии 1.8.2 на версию 1.11. Столкнулся с проблемой с которой не могу справиться. Та модель таблиц, которая превосходно работала в 1.8.2, перестала работать в версии 1.11, и вываливается с ошибкой:

```
core.CarModel.manufacture: (models.E006) The field 'manufacture' clashes with the field 'manufacture' from model 'core.page'.
```

По всей видимости это связано с наследованием моделей, поскольку проект старый я не могу кардинально изменить схему таблиц, подскажите пожалуйста как выйти из данной ситуации. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Я воспроизвел схему моделей, которая прекрасно работает на 1.8.2 и перестает работать на 1.11:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class InheritanceCastModel(models.Model):

    real_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.real_type = self._get_real_type()
        super(InheritanceCastModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_real_type(self):
        return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(self))

    def cast(self):
        return self.real_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.pk)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Page(InheritanceCastModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=u'Title', blank=True)


class Manufacture(Page):
    ru_title = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=u'RU Title')


class CarModel(Page):
    manufacture = models.ForeignKey(Manufacture, verbose_name=u'Manufacture')
    ru_title = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=u'RU Title')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не ошибка джанги, и не несовместимость версий.
У вас имена совпадают.

Дело в том, что модели Page, нужно имя manufacture, для доступа к модели Manufacture, а у CarModel есть поле manufacture, которое тоже надо отображать. Естественно она не может определить два одинаковых имени.

Один из вариантов решения, это переименовать поле manufacture у CarModel, либо имя модели Manufacture, чтобы имена не совпадали.

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку

Comment: Разве же это наводка? У вас там определяется отношение один-к-одному между моделями.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что можно отметить вопрос как решенный? Наверное вы правы, только я все еще надеюсь, что возможно есть какой-то способ отметить скажем в модели (некоторой инструкцией), что обращаться к полю по некоторому имени отличному от генеренного, чтобы не изменять имена таблиц или полей в таблице БД. Возможно такого способа нет, но в 1.8 ведь оно как-то работает.  По крайней мере есть способ, который вы предложили, за это огромное спасибо, по крайней мере вы внесли ясность в суть ошибки.

Comment: Этот код никак не мог работать ни в какой версии. Он мог работать только если модель Page, была абстрактной.

Comment: Для чего мне врать, поставьте в virtualenv 1.8.2 и убедитесь

Comment: Во вранье вас не обвиняют. Просто что-то проглядели.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению нет, того функционала, что вы ждёте, уже не вернут. Dmitriy Yusupov  всё правильно сказал - у вас только вариант переименовать поле или модель (назовите её CarManufacture, в чём проблема).

В 1.8.х действительно работало такое поведение, потому что на родителя в multi table inheritance ссылка называлась бы manufacture_ptr, а в django 1.9 этот функционал изменили и приравняли к названию модели. Увы, сам с таким сталкивался, внятного решения не нашёл.

Есть ещё вариант передать параметр name в поле, но это не то, что вы ожидаете от джанги, он просто переименует его в вызовах, ещё больше запутывая

```
manufacture = models.ForeignKey(Manufacture, verbose_name=u'Manufacture', name='manufacture_ptr')
```

вызовы изменятся:
`CarModel.objects.create(manufacture_ptr=Manufacture.objects.first())`